# getting a boolean value from postgresql in java

Tags: java, sql, linux, postgresql, netbeans

I am having troubles to print a boolean value from a postgresql table in java.

the table:

```
java=# select * from Materias;
 codigo | nombre | contenido | troncal 
--------+--------+-----------+---------
      1 |        |           | f
      2 |        |           | f
      3 |        |           | f
      4 |        |           | t
      5 |        |           | t
      6 |        |           | t
```

now the output using getString

```
   linea = String.format("%-15d %-20s %-10s", resultado.getInt(1), resultado.getString(2), resultado.getString(3));
    Codigo          Nombre               Troncal   
    1                                    null      
    2                                    null      
    3                                    null      
    4                                    null      
    5                                    null      
    6                                    null
```

the output using getBoolean

```
linea = String.format("%-15d %-20s %-10s", resultado.getInt(1), resultado.getString(2), resultado.getBoolean(3));

    Codigo          Nombre               Troncal   
    1                                    false     
    2                                    false     
    3                                    false     
    4                                    false     
    5                                    false     
    6                                    false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 4 columns but you're only looking at the first 3! The rs.getX(int) methods index from 1 (confusingly)

I would rewrite your select, btw, to explicitly state the columns and the order that you require them to be returned in.

Comment: It's inherently unintuitive, because Java is zero-indexed while SQL is 1-indexed (I actually forget if this is in the SQL spec, or is just how most everyone does it). So someone is bound to get confused -- either the db person writing java, or the java person using a db.

Comment: yes is unintuitive, but if it  started from zero the problem was the same. because i forgot look the table. Is better use the column names.